# How to tell if current session is holding a lock?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a query I can run in SSMS to see if the current session I am in has a lock. Like if a `BEGIN TRAN` statement was run and never resolved, is there a query that would show that? And again, specifically whether the tab/session I'm currently typing in is the one with the lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the DMV `sys.dm_tran_locks` shows all currently held or requested locks and the function `@@spid` returns the current `session_id`,

So:

```
select *
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where request_session_id = @@spid
```